# Moved TFS change build agent

Tags: tfs, build-agent

We moved our TFS on-premise to new servers, and now I have to change the build-agents (on Windows) so that they also link to the new server. Is there a more easy way to do this than to remove it and reconfigure it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer via *[Unconfig remove service registration should be best effort](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-agent/issues/901)*  (after a bit of reading between the lines).

Edit the `setting.json` file in your Agent directory and restart the Agent service.

Comment: In other versions, it is instead the *hidden* file `.agent` (still in JSON format). In some versions of Windows, change Windows Explorer to show hidden files: Menu *"Tools"* → *"Folder options"* → tab *"View"*, and enable *"Show hidden files, folders, and drives"*.